# What happens when If function's result will be wrong?

Tags: objective-c

I am learning objective-c when this thing come and bother me.

I tried to make a program that will return which PDF should be shown when the user input specific things.

My code looks like this

```
filePath = (userChooseA) ? @"firstFilePath" : @"secondFilePath";
```

By right if User choose A, the file path will be firstFilePath and vice versa.

However, when I purposely input the non existent file for firstFilePath, the system will directly show secondFilePath regardless user's choice.

My Question is,

why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Thank You,

Regards

Comment: what is the type of userChooseA?  also how did you go about determining that userChooseA is what you think it is

Comment: You will have to show more code.  The single line you show is fine (except you don't need the parentheses) and there is no reason that the second PDF will be shown, provided `userChooseA == YES`, so there is probably a bug elsewhere.

Comment: The other part of the code is really simple, it's just defining some variables and how to display the file.

Comment: To answer Fonix's question, the type of userChooseA is bool. and how do I determine if user choose A is by clicking "A" Button.

Answer (score 1):

That's because this statement is equivalent to:

```
if(userChooseA)
{
    filePath = @"firstFilePath";
}else{
    filePath = @"secondFilePath";
}
```

I assume userChooseA is a BOOL set somewhere else in your code when comparing paths, and it's false if the user chooses B or any other path.

Which means that unless the user chooses A, the file path will be B.

If you want to do something else if neither A or B are chosen, you could write (again assuming UserChooseA and userChooseB are Bool set somewhere else in your code):

```
int fileSelection = 3;
If (userChooseA) fileSelection = 0;
If (userChooseB) fileSelection = 1;

switch (fileSelection) {
    case 0:
        filePath = @"firstFilePath";
        break;
    case 1:
        filePath = @"secondFilePath";
        break;
    default:
        ... do something else...
        break;
}
```

if this is off base, as suggested in the comments we need to see more code about what type userChooseA is and how it gets set.

Comment: The OP appears to already know this and wants to know why the second PDF is being used despite `userChooseA` being `YES` (this is how I interpreted the question, at least).

Comment: yeah you are right droopy, I wanted to know why second PDF is being used despite user's choose.

Comment: So what is the code for the IBAction when the A or B buttons are clicked? How is userChooseA initialized?

Comment: The assumption is that userChooseA is set to YES, but I think it's not for some reason.